# Blazor - Could not reconnect to the server. Reload the page to restore functionality

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, disconnect

I have developed Blazor Server Server application and customers obviously do not like the message
"Could not reconnect to the server. Reload the page to restore functionality" in case of connection issue.

I explored migration to Web assembly, but customer did not like the loading time and amount of data transferred. Some users (with paid mobile data ) might be sensitive to MBs transferred.

Is there a way how to have page displayed during connection disruption (e.g. mobile user traveling in subway) without the message
"Could not reconnect to the server. Reload the page to restore functionality" and user can continue after the connection is restored ?

P.S. Web assembly loading time can be solved by solution described  here [Blazor - Web assembly loading time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70330321/blazor-web-assembly-loading-time)

Comment: Blazor Server model is not suitable for mobile user traveling in subway.
 By definition is requires stable connection. Do you actually need SPA? Either consider asp.net core Razor Pages or MVC, or if you need SPA, some javascript framework

Comment: @Liero, you are right. I am aware of this now. Unfortunately the project gradually evolved from back end project to font end development, which I was not familiar with (except simple Blazor apps for IT department, which is very different from "fancy web sites for end users"). I was not aware how complicated will be solve all Blazor differences....